# How to prevent multiple workers from racing to process the same task?

Tags: mysql, ruby, concurrency, backgroundworker

I start this worker 10 times to give it a sense of concurrency:

```
class AnalyzerWorker
  @queue = :analyzer

  def self.perform
    loop do
      # My attempt to lock pictures from other worker instances that may
      # try to analyze the same picture (race condition)

      pic = Pic.where(locked: false).first
      pic.update_attributes locked: true 

      pic.analyze
    end
  end
end
```

This code is actually still vulnerable to race condition, one of the reasons i think is because there's a gap of time between fetching the unlocked picture and actually locking it.

Maybe there's more reasons, any robust approach to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Active Record provides optimistic locking and pessimistic locking.

> In order to use [optimistic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#optimistic-locking) locking, the table needs to have a column
>   called lock_version of type integer. Each time the record is updated,
>   Active Record increments the lock_version column. If an update request
>   is made with a lower value in the lock_version field than is currently
>   in the lock_version column in the database, the update request will
>   fail with an ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError.
>
> [Pessimistic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pessimistic-locking) locking uses a locking mechanism provided by the
>   underlying database. Using lock when building a relation obtains an
>   exclusive lock on the selected rows. Relations using lock are usually
>   wrapped inside a transaction for preventing deadlock conditions.

Code samples are provided in the referenced links...

Either should work but each need different implementations. From what you are doing, I'd consider pessimistic locking since the possibility of a conflict is relatively high.

Your current implementation is kind of a mixture of both however, as you indicated, it really doesn't solve the problem.  You might be able to make yours work, but using the Active Record implementation makes sense.

Comment: Any progress?  Did this help?  Anything else I can do?

Comment: Did this solve your problem?  If not, do you have questions?  If yes, can you accept it?  Thanks...